# Setting the location of my object

Tags: modeling, origin

I have accidentally applied the location of my object in blender and my object has now zeroed out. How do i fix this?

Comment: Did you try Command-Z?

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what location you had your object at previously, you can go into edit mode, with your cursor on the origin, use `Selection to Cursor (Keep Offset)`. Then, back in object mode, change the position again to the same place it was before.

If you don't know the coordinates of its original location, you could just estimate them, or you could, in edit mode, press N, and average the locations of the individual vertices to find the original position, but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: The "origin to geometry" function exactly calculates the average location of every vertex.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the *Transform Panel* then type in the location or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (if you have closed it then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> won't work).